# I am getting error in eclipse while installing ObjectAid

Tags: eclipse, objectaid

Below is the error I am getting

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed

Unable to read repository at http://www.objectaid.net/update/plugins/com.objectaid.uml_1.1.10.jar.

Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 1107319; received: 367016

session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).

Comment: This could be a bug, here's a [very similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38885311/objectaid-uml-plugin-for-eclipse).

Comment: so how can I install it in eclipse or it there is any other alternative to this you can suggest

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution at https://mcuoneclipse.com/2015/06/15/workaround-for-installing-software-has-encountered-a-problem-in-eclipse/.

I unchecked the option to **Contact all update sites during install to find required software** in the Available Software menu and it worked:

[image: Disabled Contact all update sites during install to find required software]