# ObjectAid UML plugin for Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, objectaid

I have a problem with the installation ObjectAid UML plugin for Eclipse.

```
‘Installing Software’ has encountered a problem.
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=_home_aleksandar_eclipse_java-neon4_eclipse, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Unable to read repository at http://www.objectaid.net/update/plugins/com.objectaid.uml_1.1.10.jar.
Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 1107319; received: 940909
```

I unchecked 'Contact all update sites during install to find required software, but doesn't work. 
Does anyone know what's the problem?

Comment: It may be a bug, a [very similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38882126/i-am-getting-error-in-eclipse-while-installing-objectaid) was asked four hours ago.

Comment: Are you upgrading from a previous version of ObjectAid or are you doing a fresh install of ObjectAid? From the [ObjectAid update website](http://www.objectaid.net/) - "it is not possible to upgrade to version 1.1.7 or later of the Class Diagram from a version before 1.1.7".